# Stored Value in Checkbox and Capture Submitted Values Checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `ASP:DataList`.  Inside the `DataList`, I have the code below which displays the Name and Checkbox for each row.

What I would like to do is:

1. Store the Name in a hidden field.
2. Loop through all the checkboxes, find the ones that are checked and `INSERT` the value into the database.

If possible, please provide some sample code.

```
<td style="width: 600px"><%#Eval("Name></td>
<td style="width: 20px">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is fine.

Just in your postback, loop though the check box and check

```
foreach (Checkbox cb in YOurcheckboxlist)
 {
      if (cb.Checked) {
// get the name and insert
}
 }
```

Comment: I tried, but did not find the Checkbox. I have a submit button (Button1), with onclick="Button1_Click". Can you show me how to process this?

Comment: how did you add the Checkbox onto the page??

Comment: The checkboxes are in the DataList rows. Not sure how to Submit, and capture those values that checked.  thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the hint. Basically, I use Label to hide the Value for each row, then loop through when the form submitted to capture the checkbox true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Had this situation before, this is what I did,

in the form_Sumbit event,

```
foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
 {
            if (ctl is CheckBox)
            {
                //check for checked or not and store the value into an array or a List.
            }
 }
```

Not a perfect solution, let's see if someone can come up with a better idea.

Comment: How do I store the value Eval("Name")? in each checkbox? or extract directly from the rows that checked? Totally, lost.